# Why my hashing password through bcrypt is differnet when it store in database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, authentication, encryption, bcrypt

I encrypt password through bcrypt but when i check hashed password in console.log it is different from the hashed password that will store in database. So when i compare password through bcrypt at the time of login showing incorrect password.

```
const user = require('../models/userModel');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const handelNewUser = async (req,res) => {
    const {name,email,password} = req.body;

    if(!name || !email || !password){return res.status(400) .json(`message:Please fill all the fields`)}
    const userExist = await user.findOne({email}).exec();
    if(userExist){return res.status(400).json(`message:User already exist`)}

    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password,10);
    console.log(hash);
    const newUser = new user({
        name,
        email,
        password:hash
    });
    console.log(newUser);
    newUser.save()
    .then(() => {
        res.json({
            message:'User Created Successfully'
        })
        //console.log(newUser)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({
            message:err
        })
    })

    

}

module.exports = {handelNewUser};
```

i will get output in console.log for newUser
[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTkUn.png)

and the newUser password which store in database
[data in mongodb database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p0n2.png)

Comment: Tip: Since you're using an `async` function, just `await` here. Don't mess around with the crappy old `then()` and `catch()` method. If you want to rescue errors you can do it with the regular [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) approach.

Comment: Is there a save hook that is re-encrypting the password?

Comment: Please post text rather than image links. Then, for example, we could check whether Joe's suggestion is correct if it turns out verifying the initially encoded password against the one in the DB succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Bcrypt produces different output each time it is run for the same input passphrase *by design*. This is so you can't create lookup tables for passwords like you might with obsolete techniques like unsalted MD5.

If it produced the same output, your Bcrypt implementation would be broken.

Comment: actually in this i think bcrypt is working but hte difference is that when i store password in database it was different from when i console.log the same newUseer details.
`console.log(hash);
    const newUser = new user({
        name,
        email,
        password:hash
    });
    console.log(newUser);
    newUser.save()`

Comment: What sort of values are you getting for the password `"test"`? I get values like `'$2b$10$yRFVwtXdUTtepKO8vY0CzO3y6QB.jPMPYYqyyTZZnx2QFZXKpnMZO'` or `'$2b$10$LTYK6E/Qex1kmcutQpAMguR6rkx/4ZufMTk/QULCtpEjjGNBarfUW'`.

Comment: It's worth checking that your `user` model doesn't *already* hash passwords. If you're using something like Passport that can be taken care of automatically.